# How RTOS scheduling differs from simple Timer scheduling?

Tags: operating-system, embedded, scheduled-tasks

How does RTOS task scheduling differ from simply triggering tasks from a periodic timer in an embedded system.

Comment: 1) Don't spam tags! 2) You compare apples and oranges. 3) Too broad.

Comment: @Olaf I am really new to Stackoverflow. I apologize if my question is too broad. However, I would highly appreciate if you could help me with this question.

Comment: Simplify your question and make it more specific to avoid closure.  For example you might ask "How does RTOS task scheduling differ from simply triggering tasks from a periodic timer?"  You might also include an example of your timer triggered scheduling (perhaps as pseudo-code) to make it clear what you mean as the description could imply a number of implementations with different scheduling properties and software architectures.

Comment: @Clifford Thank you. I wasn't specific.  I will rephrase my question.

Comment: Maybe Im late to the game here, the question and answer seem pretty good.  Maybe it was edited.

Comment: It we cant get it reopened then you will need to ask again using the suggested question.

Comment: @old_timer: THe question is celarly too broad, as it asks to compare two general concepts. Asking the same question twice is a violation of site-rules. Please don't recommend that!

Comment: so how does the person get an answer?

Comment: I think there is potentially a good question here, but even with the edit Premhas failed to add a description of what he means by "triggering tasks from a periodic timer" since that could mean a number of architectures including an RTOS;  I have assumed he simply means time triggered execution of run-to-completion functions with no preemption - but that is an assumption.

Comment: This https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time-triggered_architecture is probably a better answer than I have given.  It correctly identifies _time-triggered architecture_ as a subset of _event triggered architecture_ more normally associated with an RTOS.  It also mentions hybrid schedulers supporting preemption.  The point being that without elaboration on what you mean by "_timer scheduling_" the question remains too broad since there is a continuum of architectures from simply time-triggered execution to pre-emptive time triggering to a fully event triggered RTOS.

Answer (score 1):

> Real Time Operating System, which run the tasks periodically just like
>   the timers,

That is not how an RTOS schedules tasks.  An RTOS task is scheduled when a *scheduling event* upon which it is waiting occurs, of which *time* is just one such event and the least appropriate if real-time response to asynchronous external events is required.

If all your tasks run periodically (time-triggerered) it is true that you *may* not need an RTOS, but you have to be able to guarantee that in the worst case - when the maximum number of tasks trigger at the same time, the total execution time for all those tasks is not longer that the time the next task will be due is hard-realtime constraints are to be met.

In an RTOS tasks have *scheduling priority*, so if a low priority task has not completed when a higher priority task becomes due, the lower priority task will be preempted and the higher priority task will run ensuring deterministic maximum delay of each task - being the sum of the execution times of all higher priority tasks rather then just all tasks regardless of priority.  Scheduling delays overall are minimised by *rate-monotonic scheduling* where the shortest most deterministic tasks are given the highest priority, while tasks that take a long or non-deterministically variable time run at a lower priority (effectively as background tasks).

Comment: Is it possible to implement priority in periodic Timers for scheduling tasks ?

Comment: @Prem : You ought really to ask another question if you have another question - the question quality police are ruthless however as you have found, so consider the question carefully.

Comment: @Prem : However, if you have implemented preemptive priority with context switching, then you have written at least the kernel of an RTOS, so the answer to your question would be that there is no difference. But I have assumed that you mean something simpler - time-triggered execution of run-to-completion functions running in a single context (i.e. a single stack, no preemption).

Comment: @Prem : On the other hand, if your "tasks" are in fact interrupt handlers on independent hardware timers and those timer interrupts have different priority levels, then you could rather inflexibly perhaps achieve preemptive priority based scheduling.  These three interpretations of what you might mean by "Timer Scheduling" illustrate how your question remains too broad.